# Why can't I create a system restore point on Windows 10?

Tags: system-restore

I want to create a system restore point. My pc has two internal drives installed: C, where Windows is installed, and D, where Ubuntu and most of programs are installed and all media are stored. 
I want to create the restore point on my second internal drive (D), if possible.

I'm on the property manager now and I cannot select "create a system restore point" ->

[image: cannot create a restore point]

---

When I select "configure" and the other window opens I cannot select the "Activate system protection" ->

---

[image: cannot activate system protection]

Some additional info about my system ->

I did a clean installation of Windows 10 x64 (from ISO on usb stick, I didn't select format before installing) and since then I only installed Solidworks 2016 and Bitdefender 2017 (both are original) and deactivate the UAC.
After each new installation I usually run the registry cleanup tool both on Glary Utilities and on CCleaner and I always find a lot of issues; anyhow I don't mind because the system is clean, installed right now, with only two programs installed.

**What am I supposed to do for being able creating a system restore point?**
I tried deactivating Bitdefender protection so far but it didn't work.

---

Comment: See if this works. Open cmd prompt as administrator and run the following command:  `reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SPP\Clients" /v " {09F7EDC5-294E-4180-AF6A-FB0E6A0E9513}" /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "1" /f `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Windows system restore point can only be saved on C:\ if Windows is installed there, so I have to use C:\ , instead than D:\, to create it.

I  followed the instructions below->

> Each drive can be setup for restoring that drive, but a restore point
>   cannot be saved to another drive.
>
> Windows System Restore is capable of monitoring anything installed to
>   your Windows OS, even on other partitions/drives

For my D:\ drive has Linux installed, i.e. another operative system, that may be the reason why I cannot create a restore point for Windows there.
 For Windows is installed on C:\ I can create my windows restore point there; so I have to repeat all the operations described in the Question (selecting the drive and configure it) by keeping C:\ instead than D:\

So here is what I did to solve the problem:

I searched "Restore" on the Window search bar and then select "Create a restore point". In the property manager which opened all my drives had the protection disabled and so I could not configure any restore point (the "Create" button was disabled) ->

[image: cannot click on create]

I selected C:\ and then click on "Configure"; I activated system protections in the window which opened, applied and saved->

[image: change to C:\]

I returned to the previous property manager window and select "Create" to create a new system restore point; then a third window opened asking me to name it ->

[image: name it]

The restore point was successfully created.